# How to keep data private to other users using FileMaker Pro?

Tags: filemaker

I have created a database using FileMaker Pro, how do I keep previously entered data on FileMaker Pro private to other users who wants to enter new data?

Answer (score 1):

You can limit users access to records by tagging the records with the account name that created them, and setting the users' privilege set to allow access only when:

```
Get (AccountName) = YourTable::CreatedBy
```

See:
http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/create_db.8.23.html#1029444
http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/passwords.14.20.html#1028570